# Swift Vapor: catchMap not being awaited

Tags: swift, future, vapor

I have the following section of code in a controller, which queries MailGun to send an email, and then should ideally wait for a response before returning in the controller. As configured right now, this **should** fail as I have intentionally broken my MailGun configuration. But currently the controller is returning a success status, because the `.catchMap` functionality is not being properly awaited, and I'm not sure how to correctly structure my code so that it is.

```swift
return emailTemplate.render(emailData, on: req).map { message -> Future<Response> in
    let deliveryService = try req.make(EmailDeliveryService.self)
    return try deliveryService.send(message, on: req)
}.catchMap { error in
    /// this is not being awaited, and no abort is thrown before the request returns
    throw Abort(.internalServerError, reason: "Error sending email.")
}.transform(to: savedObj)
```

The function that should be properly awaited, `deliverService.send`, has the method signature:

```swift
func send(_ message: EmailMessage, on container: Container) throws -> Future<Response>
```

How can I appropriately structure this code to correctly catch an error that is returned by the result of the `deliveryService.send` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `render()` method signature is something like this:

```swift
func render(…) -> Future<String>
```

then, I think you need to use `flatMap` instead of `map` in:

```swift
return emailTemplate.render(emailData, on: req).map // <—
```

Right now, the `catchMap` and `transform` method are receiving a `Future<Future<Response>>` because `map` only transform the encapsulated data of the given future which go like this:

```
Future<String> -map(String -> Future<Response)-> Future<Future<Response>>
```

Using `flatMap`, it will flatten the double Future, which is the purpose of this method which lead to:

```
Future<String> -flatMap(String -> Future<Response)-> Future<Response>
```

Then, the `catchMap` will be able to access the error.